# Only setting one field in a Rust `Default` implementation

Tags: rust, traits

I have a Rust `struct` with a large number of fields, all of which are themselves `Default`. I'd like to create a custom `impl Default` for it, with the following semantics:

1. One of the fields has a custom value
2. All other fields get their value from their `Default::default`

Here's how I hoped to do that:

```
impl Default for Foo {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            thing: 2,
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
}
```

...but that actually causes unchecked recursion, since `..Default::default()` calls `Self::default()` rather than `$member::default()` for each member of `Self`.

Is there any way to accomplish this, short of writing a custom macro or explicitly listing every field?

Comment: well, you could write the defaults youself. With the help of some IDE or tool should be a matter of seconds. A macro would do too, but how would you discriminate the fields you do not want to add to the expansion?

Comment: "_Is there any way to accomplish this, short of writing a custom macro or explicitly listing every field?_" Since `#[derive(Default)]` itself is a macro that lists every field with `field: Default::default()`, there's probably no better way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [use the `derivative` crate](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/latest/Default.html#setting-the-value-of-a-field) to achieve this. It provides alternative versions of some of the standard library derive macros with additional customizability:

```
#[derive(Debug, Derivative)]
#[derivative(Default)]
struct Foo {
    foo: u8,
    #[derivative(Default(value="2"))]
    thing: u8,
}
```

Just using the standard library, you can either derive `Default` to get the default values for all fields, or implement it completely manually.

Comment: this is really handy

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want, thanks! Will accept when SO allows me to.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a custom function into value instead of just 2?

Comment: @qwer I think the string passed in as `value` is actually an expression, so using `value = "my_fun()"` should work as well. Maybe you need a fully qualified path for the function. I suggest you simply try it.